# Rails 4 - Insert duplicate ActiveRecord data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I developed pointing some object and below is my code.

```
if ObjectRating.where(user_id: current_user.id, object_id: @object.id).present?
    rating = ObjectRating.where(user_id: current_user.id, object_id: @object.id).first
    if rating.update_attributes(rating_params)
      @jsonResult.object = rating
    else
      @jsonResult.status = false
      @jsonResult.message = "Please Retry"
    end 
  else
    rating = @object.object_ratings.new(rating_params)
    rating.user_id = current_user.id

    if rating.save
      @jsonResult.object = rating
    else
      @jsonResult.status = false
      @jsonResult.message = "Please Retry"
    end 
  end
```

Rating params is

```
private
def rating_params
  params.require(:object_rating).permit(:rating)
end
```

It works good but sometime insert duplicate data in to database.

---

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id, object_id , user_id, rating, created_at, updated_at  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1, 100, 200, 8 ,2015-06-26 10:52:34, 2015-06-26 10:52:48 |
| 2, 100, 200, 8 ,2015-06-26 10:52:34, 2015-06-26 10:52:34 |
| 3, 120, 230, 8 ,2015-06-26 10:54:32, 2015-06-26 10:54:32 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

ID `1`, `2` is same object .

I checked before save in controller, Why it create duplicate record for the next one?

Comment: What happens when you add `:id` to `rating_params` `params.require(:object_rating).permit(:id, :rating)`?

Comment: @Pavan this method running on **member** not **collection**, and then  codes not need `:id` . Line 10 is get `@object = Model.where(id: params[:id]).first` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add indexing of following columns `object_id , user_id, rating`.
Create migration like,

```
add_index :object_ratings, [:object_id , :user_id, :rating], unique: true
```

Comment: If you're desiring unique values, add `, unique: true` to the end of the `add_index`.

Comment: While  this answer will fix your problem, your original problem of creating duplicate records will be stay the same. I think you would put a debugger and see how if flows through the condition ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try uniqueness validation with scope.

```
validates :uniqueness => { scope: [:user_id, :object_id] }
```

Answer (score 1):

All the ruby objects are inherited from the class `Object` directly or indirectly

Ex:

`String.superclass -> Object < BasicObject`

and every object has its object id

`ObjectRating.object_id -> <some lenghthy number>`

So when you search for `object_id` it actually search for base object id and hence you always gets results as not found

then as per your code, you save the record again.

My advice is to get rename the column ‘object_id’ in to something else (not to conflict with ruby/rails internals)

Comment: I got it. But I change to **object_id** for question, originally column name is not object_id :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
...
else
    rating = ObjectRating.new(rating_params)
    rating.user_id = current_user.id
...
```

Why? How many an objects will be create when `@object.object_ratings.new`?
Sometime it will possible creating Object.new(object_raing.params) and Object_ratings.new(params) both (or triple).